# Validate e-mail address when pressing a button

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a basic login screen. However, I'm struggling with the e-mail validation.

Every time I press a button, I want to make sure that the user inputs the correct e-mail format, or give them a small alert under the e-mail TextInput if they write something other than a valid e-mail (this alert will be hidden by default.). However, when I try, it always gives me this error (regardless of the user input):

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.username')
```

This is my code so far

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
 state = { username: null, password: null }
 show = false;

 _validar = (text) => {
  let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/ ;

  if(reg.test(text) === false) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
 }

 _onSubmit() {
  if(this._validar(this.state.username) == true) {
    const { username, password } = this.state;
  } else {
    this.show = true;
  }
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <KeyboardAwareScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container} scrollEnabled 
   enableOnAndroid={true} resetScrollToCoords={{x:0, y:0}}> 
    <View style={styles.logo}>
     <Image source = {logo} style={styles.img}/>
     <Text style={styles.textLogoPrimary}>Neuron App</Text>
     <Text style={styles.textLogoSecondary}>Test</Text>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.formElement}>
     <Text style={styles.formText}>Correo Electrónico</Text>
     <TextInput keyboardType='email-address' placeholder='Email' onChangeText={value => this.setState({ username: value })} 
     style={styles.formInput} />
     {this.state.show ? (
       <Text style={styles.textAlert}>Correo Electrónico no valido.</Text> 
     ) : null}       
    </View>

    <View style={styles.formElement}>
     <Text style={styles.formText}>Contraseña</Text>
     <TextInput style={styles.formInput} onChangeText={value => this.setState({ password: value })} secureTextEntry={true}/>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.buttonView}>
     <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this._onSubmit}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Iniciar</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>     
  </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
 );
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your onSubmit funciton to "

```
 _onSubmit = () =>{
  if(this._validar(this.state.username) == true) {
    const { username, password } = this.state;
  } else {
    this.show = true;
  }
 }
```

ES^ binds this automatically. Hope it solves the error

Comment: Hi. what does ‘const { username, password }’ do and what does it called?

Answer (score 0):

This error is raised because you are accessing the `this.state.username` before it is assigned. I would recommend you to change the initial state value of `username` into a string, as it ends up being a string, instead of `null`.

```
state = { username: '', password: '' };
```

`null` can be avoided in string case, by just assigning it `''` an empty string. If you are to evaluate it logically, it would give you same result as `null` as it is 'falsy'.